# th:field generates a wrong name attribute value after reloading a fragment with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

**The context:**

I'm reloading a div that contains a fragment using jquery .load to call a spring controller, returning the very own fragment. The html (let's assume it is called "xfile.html") looks similar to this:

```
<form th:object="${bean}" id="xform">
   <div th:fragment="xfrag" id="xid">
      <input th:field="*{attribute.subAttribute}" th:value="*{attribute.subAttribute}">
   <div>
</form>
```

The ajax call looks like this:

```
$("#xid").load("[[@{/path}]]",$("#xform").serializeArray(), function(response, status, http){});
```

And the controller returns the fragment itself:

```
@PostMapping("/path")
public String xpath(@ModelAttribute Bean bean, Model model) {
    return  "fragments/xfile :: xfrag";
}
```

**The problem:**

When the page is accessed for the first time, th:field has generated for the input an input with the name `attribute.subAttribute`. This is the expected th:field behavior and it works correctly, and the controller gets the bean.attribute.subAttribute filled with the input contents.

The issue comes when the fragment is reloaded after the first ajax call: the input will have the name `subAttribute`. This makes the input useless of course, and the bean received in the controller doesn't receive the input content.

Why is th:field generating the wrong name for the input after an ajax call?

Comment: I'm guessing when you call it with ajax it doesn't have access to the`<form th:object="${...}" />` (but it does when you load the page initially).

Comment: @Metroids I can't find anywhere in the documentation that doing so is forbidden though :/ But yeah that's a possibility.